# Should SHM file be copied along-with SQLite DB to save state?

Tags: database, sqlite

Our application needs to query some data from the SQLite database which belongs to another application and which runs in WAL mode. We copy the database files to a temporary location and open the database from that location.

Do we need to copy the **.shm** file to temporary location along-with the **.db** and **.wal** files before opening the database, to get the accurate, latest snapshot of the original application's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-shm` file does not actually contain any data; it's used only to manage shared memory for multiple processes accessing the same database file.

It is recreated automatically if missing, so you do not need to copy it.